# Not allow user to delete document in library

Tags: sharepoint

I want to develop a solution,not allow any user to delete document in library.
Can I do this client side? 
Thanks

Comment: What do you mean by *client side*? Without deploying custom code on the server? Do you know how to configure permission levels? http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-sharepoint-services-help/permission-levels-and-permissions-HA010100149.aspx

Answer (score 1):

One option is to setup permissions so the user cannot delete items. If you need to do something programatically, there is an ItemDeleting even that fires (server side) whenever an item is being deleted that you could then implement any kind of custom logic your application rules require. More info on [ItemDeleting](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/Section/Programming-Event-Handling-in-Windows-SharePoint-Services.id-306329.html) from Wrox

John

Answer (score 0):

You also could define a retention policy on the document library - if you go to settings you'll find the Information management policy settings - however I agree with John and I think managing permissions is the correct way to go.